# mod rewrite problem

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i tried this code to hide the php file extension

i have this url http://localhost/login/emprego.php and i want http://localhost/login/emprego

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

and this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

but the result is the url with the file extension in the two cases. I already restarted the apache server

what is the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if mode_rewrite is On in your httpd.conf file, because it this rewrite rules supposed to work just fine

Comment: the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is uncommented

Comment: i have a problem in my htaccess file type, now solved, thanks